# Cannot debug .NET framework source in Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to debug the .Net framework source using VS2008 SP1. It is giving me the message :

```
Source Code cannot be loaded
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed the steps in this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)?

To quote above:

> The most recent version of Visual Studio provides new features for
>   .NET Framework debugging. To debug .NET Framework source, you must
>   have access to debugging symbols for the code. You also need to enable
>   stepping into .NET Framework source.
>
> You can enable .NET Framework stepping and symbol downloading in the
>   Options dialog box. When you enable symbol downloading, you can choose
>   to download symbols immediately or just enable the option for later
>   downloading. If you do not download the symbols immediately, symbols
>   will be downloaded the next time that you start debugging your
>   application. You also can do a manual download from the Modules window
>   or the Call Stack window

.